# Nearby Place is not being shown

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I'm making a **Find nearby vape store App**. But when I click find vape store, the map won't show the place. Below is the code:-

```
btnFind.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
            sb.append("&key=" + API_KEY_SERVER);
            sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
            sb.append("&radius=10000");
            sb.append("&keyword=Vape");
            sb.append("&sensor=true");
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,
                    "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new PlacesTask().execute(sb.toString());
        }
```

Comment: I don't know of the format for what the task, but just an off chance...do you mean to have a delimiter of `&` with your location attribute?  Manually compare the result of your URL and if that doesn't work pasting from the code then perhaps you can add/remove attibutes until some do work.

Comment: @JaySnayder :: Sorry, I just now read your comment! I Didn't see that you had already pointed out the same potential error. If you want to provide an answer I will delete mine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if you have perhaps missed an `&` in the construction of the paramerters. The `location` parameter is not prepended by an ampersand. Try this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    sb.append("&key=" + API_KEY_SERVER);
    sb.append("&location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
    sb.append("&radius=10000");
    sb.append("&keyword=Vape");
    sb.append("&sensor=true");
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    new PlacesTask().execute(sb.toString());
}
```

Also note that the `sensor` parameter is no longer required.